# Windows PFX certificate import: protect private key using virtualization-based security?

Tags: certificates, windows, key-management, virtualization, pfx

On Windows 10 v1803 (i.e. April 2018 update) when importing a PFX, an option like

`[ ] Protect private key using virtualization-based security (non-exportable)`

appears on the import wizard. What is the underlying technology and it's mechanics from security perspective?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Virtualized-Based Security (VBS) uses TPM module to store keys. The key is accessible from within OS, but won't be available if OS is changed. More details on VBS: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/oem-vbs

Comment: Does VBS prevent keys to be exported in cleartext as a regular smart card could do?.

Comment: Yes, VBS does this.